# TeeChart LinearGauge Series Negative to Positive Range with Zero in the middle

Tags: c#, .net, teechart, gauge

I would like to know if there is a way to configure a LinearGauge Series to be able to display Negative and Positive Values with Zero as the starting point (in the middle). I want to embed it on a chart displaying a FastLine Series, and the Gauge must indicate a Velocity, which may be negative...So, for ex, a Velocity of -25 must start at 0 and extend to the left to -25, and a Velocity of 50 must start at 0 and extend to the right to 50.

Here is some code:

```
    velocityGuage = tChart1.Series[1] as Steema.TeeChart.Styles.LinearGauge;
    velocityGuage.Minimum = -50;
    velocityGuage.Maximum = 50;
    velocityGuage.Value = -25;
```

I discovered this link: http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=12778, but the solution did not work...I find that the bar is always "clamped" to the left side of the Gauge,,,The bar starts at -50 and ends at -25!

Can you please advise??

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a timer to try to achieve as you want. You can do something as next:

```
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  tChart1 = new Steema.TeeChart.TChart();
  this.Controls.Add(tChart1);
  tChart1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
  InitializeChart();
}
Steema.TeeChart.Styles.LinearGauge linearGauge; 
private void InitializeChart()
{
  linearGauge = new LinearGauge(tChart1.Chart);
  linearGauge.Add(-50);
  linearGauge.Add(-25);
  linearGauge.Add(0);
  linearGauge.Add(25);
  linearGauge.Add(50);

  linearGauge.Maximum = 50;
  linearGauge.Minimum = -50;
  linearGauge.UseValueColorPalette = true;
  //InitialzieSubLines
  linearGauge.GreenLineStartValue = -50;
  linearGauge.GreenLineEndValue = 0;
  linearGauge.RedLineStartValue = 25;
  linearGauge.RedLineEndValue = 50;
  linearGauge.Value = -25; 
  timer1 = new Timer();
  timer1.Start(); 
  timer1.Tick +=timer1_Tick;

}
```

Could you tell us if previous code works in your end? Remember adapt the values according to your needs

Thanks,